# Validating user input using cin

Tags: c++, validation, input

Im trying to do this:
if the value is greater than 50 or less than -50, or not an integer, than cin again the value (until it is valid)

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < cities; i++)
{
    for (size_t j = 0; j < days; j++)
    {
        cout << "temperature(" << i + 1 << ',' << j + 1 << ") = ";
        cin >> *(temperatures + i * days + j);
        while (!(*(temperatures + i * days + j) > 50 && *(temperatures + i * days + j) < -50))
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
            cout << "temperature(" << i + 1 << ',' << j + 1 << ") = ";
            cin >> *(temperatures + i * days + j);
        }
    }
```

if i write a number greater than 50, or less than -50 it works.

But if i write eg.:

```
temperature(1,1) = covid
```

than the next row:

```
temperature(1,1) = temperature(1,1) = temperature(1,1) = temperature(1,1) = temperature(1,1) =
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: This [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77275060/22193627) includes source code for function `get_int`, a robust function that inputs an integer from `std::cin`. `get_int` handles all the usual errors that can happen with `std::cin`, and loops until a valid integer is entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are testing the value of `*(temperatures + i * days + j)` even when the input has failed. Plus you are using ignore incorrectly (only ignoring one character instead of all outstanding characters). Plus you have overly complex code

Here's a better version

```
#include <limits> // for std::numeric_limits

cout << "temperature(" << i + 1 << ',' << j + 1 << ") = ";
int temp;
while (!(cin >> temp) || temp < -50 || temp > 50)
{
     cin.clear();
     cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
     cout << "temperature(" << i + 1 << ',' << j + 1 << ") = ";
}
temperatures[i * days + j] = temp;
```

I used a new variable `temp` to simplify the code. I included `cin >> temp` in the while loop condition thereby only checking temp if the input has succeeded, and I used `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');` to ignore all characters remaining in the input.

Note this probably isn't perfect. If you entered say `10deg` then the input would succeed (temp would equal 10) even though the input has non-digits in it. If you want to do input validation properly then the only real way is to read the input as a string, and test the string, before converting to an integer.