# Why am I getting a std::out_of_range error in C++?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to make [tic-tac-toe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe) in C++:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool X = true;
bool O = false;
bool b = true;
int a = 0;
int j = 100;
std::string game = "";
std::vector<char> c = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5','6','7','8','9'};

void check(){
    std::cout<<"Enter position: ";
    int pos;
    std::cin>>pos;
    if(c.at(pos-1)==pos){
      if(X == true){
         c[pos-1] = 'X';
         O = true;
         X = false;
         a = 0;
      }
      else if(O == true){
        c[pos-1] = 'O';
        X = true;
        O = false;
        a = 0;
      }
    }
    else{
      std::cout<<"Not empty, enter again.";
      a = 1;
    }
}

void print(){
  std::cout<<"|---|---|---|\n| "<<c.at(0)<<" | "<<c.at(1)<<" | "<<c.at(2)<<" | "<<"\n|---|---|---|\n| "<<c.at(3)<<" | "<<c.at(4)<<" | "<<c.at(5)<<" | "<<"\n|---|---|---|\n| "<<c.at(6)<<" | "<<c.at(7)<<" | "<<c.at(8)<<" | \n"<<"|---|---|---|\n";
}
int main(){
  print();
    int b = 0;
    while((X==true||O==true)&&b<9){
         check();
         while(a=1){
          check();
         }
         print();
         for(int i = 0;i<7;i+=3){
          if(c.at(i)==c.at(i+1)&&c.at(i+1)==c.at(i+2)&&c.at(i)==c.at(i+2)){
            j = i;
            break;
            }
          else{
              continue;
            }
          }
          for(int i = 0;i<3;i++){
            if(c.at(i)==c.at(i+3)&&c.at(i+3)==c.at(i+6)&&c.at(i)==c.at(i+6)){
               j = i;
               break;
               }
            else{
              continue;
            }
          }
          if(c.at(0)==c.at(4)&&c.at(4)==c.at(8)&&c.at(0)==c.at(8)){
            j = 0;
          }
          else if(c.at(2)==c.at(4)&&c.at(4)==c.at(6)&&c.at(2)==c.at(6)){
            j = 2;
          }
          if(j!=100){
            break;
          }
          b++;
    }
    if(j!=100){
      if(c.at(j)=='X'){
        game = "Won by X!";
      }
      else{
        game = "Won by O!";
      }
    }
    else if(j=100){
        game = "Draw";
    }
    std::cout<<game<<"\n";
}
```

...and I keep getting this error:

```
|---|---|---|
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
|---|---|---|
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
|---|---|---|
| 7 | 8 | 9 |
|---|---|---|
Enter position: terminate called after throwing an instance of
'std::out_of_range'
what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is
18446744073709551615) >= this->size() (which is 9)
```

So I created two functions and am calling it in the main method inside a while loop which iterates as long as bool X or bool O are true.

From what I understand the error is in the first function, but I don't see anything wrong with it.

How do I fix it?

Also, is the rest of my code correct?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You'll get an **out of range** error when the index provided is not within the range of the elements in the vector.  You should use a debugger to see why the program is trying to access an index that is not within range.

Comment: `while(a=1)` recall the comparison operator. Enable a higher level of compiler warnings.

Comment: `if(j=100)` is the same bug. Remember `=` is an assignment. `==` is a comparison.

Comment: As for the error `if(c.at(pos-1)==pos){` looks suspicious. You should check to make sure that `pos` is valid before this.

Comment: @273K I'm still getting the error.

Comment: @drescherjm well, what changes could I make?

Comment: The index `18446744073709551615` implies that you've tried to supply a negative value to `.at()` and `.at(pos-1)` looks suspicious.

Comment: `what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 
18446744073709551615) >= this->size() (which is 9)` tells you that you tried to access the `-1` position of your array. Which has valid indices of 0 ..8

Comment: The first rule of programming: if you have user input, verify it before using.

Comment: `18446744073709551615` means you used `-1` value as index.

Comment: `while(a=1)` wrong, `if(j=100)` wrong!

Comment: *what changes could I make* You could stop using global variables. They are not your friends. You also could give your variables long descriptive names.

Comment: FYI, you may want to use `'+'` for the corners.  Otherwise, IMHO, it looks like 3 traffic lanes or runways.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 4):

As others have explained in the comments, you have confused assignment (=) with the test for equality (==).

- `while(a=1)` should be `while(a==1)`.
- `if(j=100)` should be `if(j==100)`

In addition, in function `check` (which could also be named `take_turn`), the test `if(c.at(pos-1)==pos) { ... }` should be `if(c.at(pos-1)-'0'==pos) { ... }`. Subtracting `'0'` converts `c.at(pos-1)` from a `char`'s numeric value to a zero-based integer.

This fix, along with the two changes above, will get the program running, so you can play tic-tac-toe.

An additional fix is needed, however, because you failed to test the value that was entered by the user. When he/she enters an invalid position, e.g., `0`, your program will generate a subscript-out-of-range error.

##### A function that checks the input from `cin`

Wouldn't it be nice if there were an easy way to get proper input from `cin`?

Something like function `get_int` in the following code:

```cpp
int main()
{
    int pos;
    bool success = get_int("Enter position (press Enter to cancel): ", pos, 1, 9);
    if (success)
        std::cout << "You entered " << pos << ".\n\n";
    else
        std::cout << "You canceled.\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output from a sample run:

```
Enter position (press Enter to cancel): Huh?
Entries must be integers. Please reenter.

Enter position (press Enter to cancel): 3.14
Entries must be integers. Please reenter.

Enter position (press Enter to cancel): 3.
Entries must be integers. Please reenter.

Enter position (press Enter to cancel): 0
0 is out of range. Please reenter.
Entries must be integers between 1 and 9.

Enter position (press Enter to cancel): -1
-1 is out of range. Please reenter.
Entries must be integers between 1 and 9.

Enter position (press Enter to cancel): 10
10 is out of range. Please reenter.
Entries must be integers between 1 and 9.

Enter position (press Enter to cancel): 9
You entered 9.
```

On the next run, the user cancels.

```
Enter position (press Enter to cancel): 1x
Entries must be integers. Please reenter.

Enter position (press Enter to cancel): x1
Entries must be integers. Please reenter.

Enter position (press Enter to cancel): 1 x
Entries must be integers. Please reenter.

Enter position (press Enter to cancel): x 1
Entries must be integers. Please reenter.

Enter position (press Enter to cancel):
Canceled...

You canceled.
```

`get_int` should execute this algorithm:

1. Display a prompt, and read a line of text into a string.
2. Trim any whitespace found at either the beginning or end of the string.
3. If the resulting string is empty, cancel the input operation. Return `false` to indicate that the operation was canceled.
4. At this point, the string should contain a valid `int`, and nothing else. No extra characters are allowed, either before the number or after.
5. The number entered by the user should be (inclusively) between `min` and `max`.
6. If these conditions are met, convert the string into an `int`, and store it in the argument `pos`. This is how the input value is sent back to the calling routine. Return `true` to indicate that a number was successfully extracted from `cin`.
7. Otherwise, display an error message, and ask the user to try again. Keep looping until the user either gets it right, or else cancels.

Trimming whitespace is relatively straightforward. In the default locale, there are six characters that are classified as *whitespace* by function `std::isspace`.

- space `' '`
- form feed `'\f'`
- line feed `'\n'`
- carriage return `'\r'`
- horizontal tab `'\t'`
- vertical tab `'\v'`

Those are the characters that are trimmed from a string by function `trim_whitespace`.

It uses member functions `find_first_not_of` and `find_last_not_of`, respectively, to locate the first and last non-whitespace characters in a string. It then forms a substring based on the locations.

```cpp
auto trim_whitespace(std::string const& s) -> std::string
{
    // Trim leading and trailing whitespace from string `s`.
    auto const first{ s.find_first_not_of(" \f\n\r\t\v")};
    if (first == std::string::npos)
        return {};
    auto const last{ s.find_last_not_of(" \f\n\r\t\v") };
    enum : std::string::size_type { one = 1u };
    return s.substr(first, (last - first + one));
}
```

Here is a complete program that uses function `get_int`. It generated the sample output above.

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
auto trim_whitespace(std::string const& s) -> std::string
{
    // Trim leading and trailing whitespace from string `s`.
    auto const first{ s.find_first_not_of(" \f\n\r\t\v")};
    if (first == std::string::npos)
        return {};
    auto const last{ s.find_last_not_of(" \f\n\r\t\v") };
    enum : std::string::size_type { one = 1u };
    return s.substr(first, (last - first + one));
}
bool get_int(
    std::string const& prompt,
    int& value,
    int const min = std::numeric_limits<int>::min(),
    int const max = std::numeric_limits<int>::max(),
    bool const cancel_is_allowed = true,
    std::istream& ist = std::cin,
    std::ostream& ost = std::cout)
{
    std::string s;
    for (;;)
    {
        value = 0;
        if (!prompt.empty())
            ost << prompt;
        else if (cancel_is_allowed)
            ost << "Enter an integer (press Enter to cancel): ";
        else
            ost << "Enter an integer: ";
        if (!std::getline(ist, s))
        {
            ost << "\nERROR: `std::getline` failed unexpectedly.\n\n";
            return false;
        }
        s = trim_whitespace(s);
        if (s.empty())
        {
            if (cancel_is_allowed)
            {
                ost << "Canceled...\n\n";
                return false;
            }
            ost << "Blank lines are not allowed. Please reenter.\n\n";
            continue;
        }
        std::stringstream sst(s);
        sst >> value;
        bool parses{ sst.eof() && !sst.fail() };
        bool is_in_range{ parses && min <= value && value <= max };
        if (is_in_range)
            return true;
        if (!parses)
            ost << "Entries must be integers. Please reenter.\n\n";
        else if (min != std::numeric_limits<int>::min()
            && max != std::numeric_limits<int>::max())
            ost << value << " is out of range. Please reenter.\n"
            << "Entries must be integers between " << min << " and " << max << ".\n\n";
        else if (min != std::numeric_limits<int>::min())
            ost << value << " is out of range. Please reenter.\n"
            << "Entries must be integers greater than or equal to " << min << ".\n\n";
        else
            ost << value << " is out of range. Please reenter.\n"
            << "Entries must be integers less than or equal to " << max << ".\n\n";
    }
}
int main()
{
    int pos;
    bool success = get_int("Enter position (press Enter to cancel): ", pos, 1, 9);
    if (success)
        std::cout << "You entered " << pos << ".\n\n";
    else
        std::cout << "You canceled.\n\n";
    return 0;
}
// end file: main.cpp
```

Study this code well. Lookup anything you do not understand in your textbook or on [CppReference](http://cppreference.com/).

Here are some notes about function `get_int`:

- `int& value` is a reference parameter. A reference is an alias for another variable. In this case, `value` is an alias for the corresponding argument used when `get_int` is called, i.e., it is an alias for `pos`. Any changes that function `get_int` makes to parameter `value` will automatically be made to variable `pos` in the calling routine. That is how `get_int` sends the answer back to the calling routine.
- Many paramaters have default values. Those parameters can be omitted when `get_int` is called. For example, `get_int("Enter an integer: ", value)` is all you need to input variable `value`.
- When `max` is omitted, it defaults to the largest value that can be held in a variable of type `int`. Effectively, that means there is no upper limit on the values that can be entered.
- Similarly, when `min` is omitted, it defaults to the minimum value (i.e., the largest negative value) that can be held by type `int`. Effectively, that means there is no lower limit on the values that can be entered.
- When `ist` (input stream) and `ost` (output stream) are omitted, they default, respectively, to `std::cin` and `std::cout`. Other stream objects can be used, including `stringstream` objects, which is useful when testing programs that call function `get_int`.
- `for (;;)` is an infinite loop. The only exit (here) is when a `return` statement is executed. In other programs, you will also see `break;` used to exit a loop like this one.
- `prompt.empty()` and `s.empty()` test whether a string is empty.
- `std::getline(std::cin, s)` extracts characters from `std::cin`, and stores them in string `s`, It stops when `'\n'` is encountered, but does not store `'\n'` in string `s`.
- You can test whether `getline` was successful, by using it in an if-statement. That is what `if (!std::getline(std::cin, s))` does. The details are a little tricky. `getline` returns `std::cin` (or whatever stream object is used in its call). When it is used in an if-statement (or any other context where a `bool` is expected), `std::cin` is implicitly converted to `!std::cin.fail()`, i.e., "not cin failed."
- `std::stringstream` is the type used by stringstream objects. A stringstream object is a stream object, similar to `std::cin`, except a stringstream extracts characters from a string, while `cin` gets them from the keyboard.
- `std::stringstream sst(s);` creates a stringstream object named `sst`, and loads it with the contents of string `s`.
- `sst >> value` extracts the number `value` from the stringstream, just same as `std::cin >> value` would extract it from the keyboard.
- `sst.eof()` tests whether extraction stopped because `sst` ran out of characters. "eof" means "end of file." In this program, we want to run out of characters. When we do, that means there are no stray characters following the number.
- `sst.fail()` tests whether extraction failed. Usually this occurs because `sst` encountered a non-numeric character or eof before it was able to extract a valid number.
- `bool parses` and `bool is_in_range` are boolean variables. They are used to store the answers of true/false expressions, so that they can be used later in if-statements.
- Parsing can fail for either of two reasons: 1. We did not hit eof, because there were extraneous characters after the number. 2. `sst >> value` caused `sst` to fail, because no valid number could be extracted from `sst`.

When you feel that you can explain exactly how function `get_int` works, you should show this code to your teacher, and explain that you found it on StackOverflow. Explain how it works so your teacher knows that you fully understand it.

Only then should you ask permission to use something like it in your homework assignments.

##### Be careful when mixing `get_int` and `std::cin >> value`

Function `get_int` is part of a suite of functions that handle console input, in which all the functions use `std::getline`. (See, for instance, function `press_enter_to_continue`, near the end of this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77428425/22193627).)

If you mix calls to `get_int` with operations such as `std::cin >> value;`, then you have to be careful about the hanging `'\n'` that `std::cin >> value;` leaves on the input stream. You will have to get rid of it, perhaps by calling `std::cin.ignore`, before calling `get_int`.

```cpp
    std::string name;
    int age;
    std::cout << "What is your name? ";
    std::cin >> name;
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    get_int("How old are you? ", age);
```