# cin.get() is ignored after an earlier cin.get() is used

Tags: c++

In the following program, if I press enter after the first prompt, the cin statements that follow are skipped. Does anyone know why?

This code is C++ and I am running it with Visual Studio 2022.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char string[21];

    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    cin.get(string, 20);
    cin.ignore(80, '\n');

    cout << "\nPress Enter to continue.\n";
    cin.get(string, 20);
    cin.ignore(80, '\n');

    cout << "\nPress Enter to continue.\n";
    cin.get(string, 20);
    cin.ignore(80, '\n');

    cout << "\nPress Enter to continue.\n";
    cin.get(string, 20);
    cin.ignore(80, '\n');
}
```

This code is from a 1998 textbook. I'm aware that there are more modern ways of doing this, but I would like to know why this code is malfunctioning.

Comment: What exactly are you entering in as the 1st input value? Did you check if `cin` is being put into a failure state? If you are entering more than 19 characters, `get(20)` will set `failbit` on the stream, which will cause subsequent reads to also fail until you `clear()` the failure.

Comment: "If no characters were extracted, calls `setstate(failbit)`."  Just hitting enter to continue is "no characters extracted".

Comment: @273K • https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get

Comment: @Eljay Thank you. OP seems to mislead me: *if I press enter after the **first** prompt* should be *if I press enter after the **second** prompt*

Comment: Use std::string and std::getline unless you like needless suffering.

Comment: [std::basic_istream::get](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) read `2` and `3` together. What happens to the `'\n'`?

Comment: @Paul - *"This code is from a 1998 textbook"* - There's your first mistake. A lot has happened in the last 25 years, including how we write proper C++ code. You *really* want a book from this millennium!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### A function to display `iostate`

> In the following program, if I press enter after the first prompt, the cin statements that follow are skipped. Does anyone know why?

I have modified your program so that it displays the state of `badbit`, `failbit`, and `eofbit` after each call to `std::cin`.

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <format>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

std::string iostate_info(
    std::string_view const heading,
    std::istream& ist)
{
    auto const state{ ist.rdstate() };
    bool const badbit { (state & std::ios_base::badbit ) == std::ios_base::badbit  };
    bool const failbit{ (state & std::ios_base::failbit) == std::ios_base::failbit };
    bool const eofbit { (state & std::ios_base::eofbit ) == std::ios_base::eofbit  };
    return std::format(
        "{}"
        "\n  badbit  : {}"
        "\n  failbit : {}"
        "\n  eofbit  : {}"
        "\n\n"
        , heading, badbit, failbit, eofbit);
}

int main()
{
    char string[21];

    std::cout << "Enter a string: ";
    std::cin.get(string, 20);
    std::cout << iostate_info("After FIRST std::cin.get(string, 20);", std::cin);
    std::cin.ignore(80, '\n');
    std::cout << iostate_info("After FIRST std::cin.ignore(80, '\\n');", std::cin);

    std::cout << "\nPress Enter to continue.\n";
    std::cin.get(string, 20);
    std::cout << iostate_info("After SECOND std::cin.get(string, 20);", std::cin);
    std::cin.ignore(80, '\n');
    std::cout << iostate_info("After SECOND std::cin.ignore(80, '\\n');", std::cin);

    std::cout << "\nPress Enter to continue.\n";
    std::cin.get(string, 20);
    std::cout << iostate_info("After THIRD std::cin.get(string, 20);", std::cin);
    std::cin.ignore(80, '\n');
    std::cout << iostate_info("After THIRD std::cin.ignore(80, '\\n');", std::cin);

    std::cout << "\nPress Enter to continue.\n";
    std::cin.get(string, 20);
    std::cout << iostate_info("After FOURTH std::cin.get(string, 20);", std::cin);
    std::cin.ignore(80, '\n');
    std::cout << iostate_info("After FOURTH std::cin.ignore(80, '\\n');", std::cin);
}
// end file: main.cpp
```

As you can see in the output, when `std::cin.get` is called after the first "Press Enter to continue" request, `std::cin` is placed into a failed state. That is because `'\n'` was encountered before any characters were input and stored in variable `string`.

Once `std::cin` has been placed into a failed state, no characters can be input or ignored, until the `failbit` has been cleared. Often this is done by calling `std::cin.clear()`. Because `std::cin` was not cleared, subsequent calls to `std::cin.get` and `std::cin.ignore` return without attempting to input (or ignore) any characters.

```
Enter a string: Hello, world!
After FIRST std::cin.get(string, 20);
  badbit  : false
  failbit : false
  eofbit  : false

After FIRST std::cin.ignore(80, '\n');
  badbit  : false
  failbit : false
  eofbit  : false


Press Enter to continue.

After SECOND std::cin.get(string, 20);
  badbit  : false
  failbit : true
  eofbit  : false

After SECOND std::cin.ignore(80, '\n');
  badbit  : false
  failbit : true
  eofbit  : false


Press Enter to continue.
After THIRD std::cin.get(string, 20);
  badbit  : false
  failbit : true
  eofbit  : false

After THIRD std::cin.ignore(80, '\n');
  badbit  : false
  failbit : true
  eofbit  : false


Press Enter to continue.
After FOURTH std::cin.get(string, 20);
  badbit  : false
  failbit : true
  eofbit  : false

After FOURTH std::cin.ignore(80, '\n');
  badbit  : false
  failbit : true
  eofbit  : false
```

If you press the spacebar one time before pressing Enter, then the space is stored in variable `string`, and `std::cin` does not fail.

*Side note:* I hope you recognize how error-prone it is to use the name `string` for one of your own variables in a program that also has `using namespace std;`.

##### An alternative implemention of `iostate_info`

@David C. Rankin points out in the comments below that function `iostate_info` may be easier to understand if it does not use low-level constructs such as `rdstate` and the bit-masking that goes with it. Fair enough. I guess I have been using streams for too long, because `rdstate` seemed reasonable to me! I was blind to the obvious fact that functions `bad`, `fail`, and `eof` can achieve the same results with relative ease.

David also points out the disadvantages that `std::format` imposes, because it requires a C++20 environment (or later) for `iostate_info` to compile.

Here is a rewrite that addresses both issues. For good measure, I ditched the `std::string_view`, in case a reliance on C++17 is also problematic.

```cpp
std::string iostate_info(
    std::string const& heading,
    std::istream& ist)
{
    std::stringstream sst;
    sst << std::boolalpha
        << heading 
        << "\n  badbit  : " << ist.bad()
        << "\n  failbit : " << (ist.fail() && !ist.bad())
        << "\n  eofbit  : " << ist.eof()
        << "\n\n";
    return sst.str();
}
```

##### One way to handle "Press Enter to continue..."

I am more stringent than most. When my program asks you to "Press Enter," and you enter a few garbage characters before you press Enter, it complains, and makes you try again. You must press Enter on a blank line (or a line that contains only whitespace). I do it this way, because I am concerned that the garbage characters may actually be the input intended for the next prompt.

Function `press_enter_to_continue` uses `std::getline` to input what is supposed to be a blank line. It works as part of a suite of functions that handle console input, in which all the functions use `std::getline`. (See, for instance, function `get_int`, in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77275060/22193627).)

If you mix `press_enter_to_continue` with operations such as `std::cin >> value;`, then you have to be careful about the hanging `'\n'` that `std::cin >> value;` leaves on the input stream. You will have to get rid of it, perhaps by calling `std::cin.ignore`, before calling `press_enter_to_continue`.

```cpp
void press_enter_to_continue(
    std::istream& ist = std::cin, 
    std::ostream& ost = std::cout)
{
    std::string s;
    for (;;)
    {
        ost << "Press Enter to continue...";
        if (!std::getline(ist, s))
        {
            ost << "\nERROR: `std::getline` failed unexpectedly.\n\n";
            return;
        }
        if (trim_whitespace(s).empty())
        {
            ost.put('\n');
            return;
        }
        ost << "Invalid entry. Please reenter.\n";
    }
}
```

And here is function `trim_whitespace`.

```cpp
auto trim_whitespace(std::string const& s) -> std::string
{
    // Trim leading and trailing whitespace from string `s`.
    auto const first{ s.find_first_not_of(" \f\n\r\t\v")};
    if (first == std::string::npos)
        return {};
    auto const last{ s.find_last_not_of(" \f\n\r\t\v") };
    enum : std::string::size_type { one = 1u };
    return s.substr(first, (last - first + one));
}
```

Comment: Interesting answer. Any particular reason for including `<format>` and the extended `std::cout` along with it and relegating the answer to `-std=c++20` or newer? Any particular reason for using `rdstate()` instead of simply calling `.good()`, `.bad()`, and the `.ugly()` (oh, wait), `.fail()` directly? And outputting the states, a good idea, was that to "teach a man to fish" rather than "giving him a fish"? Just curious really.

Comment: Good questions. I used `format` for two reasons: 1. I thought the code was more readable, and 2. I did not want to couple `iostate_info` to a particular output stream (or have an output stream reference as a parameter). I considered using functions `bad`, `fail`, and `eof`, but decided not to hassle decoupling `failbit` and `badbit` in the return value from `.fail()`. Once I had decided to go directly to `failbit`, for reasons of parallelism, I did the same thing for the other bits. I was also thinking that the OP might not have seen the low-level constructs before, so this was his chance!

Comment: Oh, yeah, I am all in favor of teaching folks to fish!

Comment: All valid choices, the `-std=c++20` just seemed a bit odd given "*This code is from a 1998 textbook*" in the question. The readability of the `std::cout` old vs. `format` is a taste thing. Old way, about 4 lines total (including `std::boolalpha` for the member function `true`/`false`). Good fishing lesson.