# new and delete in c++

Tags: c++, garbage

im doing an exercise and I cant understand if i'm creating garbage with this program.
As far as I understand there shouldn't be any garbage left and I should not use delete in this case, but it makes me wonder because in class the teacher said that every new has to have a delete somewhere.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool check_nr_in_array(int number, int* array_of_int_pointers[], int index);
int find_index(int number, int* array_of_int_pointers, int index);
bool mod_array_of_pointers(int number, bool presence, int* array_of_int_pointers[], int index);

int main()
{
    int* A[1000];
    int x;
    int cursor = 0;
    int alloc_var = 0;
    bool state = false;

    do
    {
        cout << "Insert a number: ";
        cin >> x;
        if(x >= 0)
        {
            state = mod_array_of_pointers(x, check_nr_in_array(x, A, cursor), A, cursor);
            if(state)
                alloc_var++;
            cursor++;
        }
    }while(x >= 0);

    cout << "Allocated" << alloc_var << " variables." << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < cursor; i++)
        cout << *(A[i]) << " ";

    return 0;
}

bool check_nr_in_array(int number, int* array_of_int_pointers[], int index)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
        if(*array_of_int_pointers[i] == number)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int find_index(int number, int* array_of_int_pointers[], int index)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
        if(*array_of_int_pointers[i] == number)
            return i;
    }
    return 0;
}
bool mod_array_of_pointers(int number, bool presence, int* array_of_int_pointers[], int index)
{
    if(!presence)
    {
        array_of_int_pointers[index] = new int;
        *array_of_int_pointers[index] = number;
        return true;
    }else{
        array_of_int_pointers[index] = array_of_int_pointers[find_index(number, array_of_int_pointers, index)];
        return false;
    }
}
```

The program works but i dont know how to check if im creating garbage somewhere.
the exercise itself is just creating an array of int pointers, and you ask for a number until the number is negative. If the inserted nr is already somewhere in the array u should copy it's address otherwise you need to allocate another var with new.

fixed the code like below, can somebody check and let me know if it's still leaking ?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool check_nr_in_array(int number, int* array_of_int_pointers[], int index);
int find_index(int number, int* array_of_int_pointers, int index);
bool mod_array_of_pointers(int number, bool presence, int* array_of_int_pointers[], int index, bool checksum[]);
void deallocate(int* array_of_int_pointers[], bool checksum[], int index);
int main()
{
    int* A[1000];
    int x;
    int cursor = 0;
    int alloc_var = 0;
    bool state = false;
    bool checksum[1000];

    do
    {
        cout << "Inserire un numero: ";
        cin >> x;
        if(x >= 0)
        {
            state = mod_array_of_pointers(x, check_nr_in_array(x, A, cursor), A, cursor, checksum);
            if(state)
                alloc_var++;
            cursor++;
        }
    }while(x >= 0);

    cout << "Allocate " << alloc_var << " variabili." << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < cursor; i++)
        cout << *(A[i]) << " ";

    deallocate(A, checksum, cursor);

    return 0;
}

bool check_nr_in_array(int number, int* array_of_int_pointers[], int index)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
        if(*array_of_int_pointers[i] == number)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int find_index(int number, int* array_of_int_pointers[], int index)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
        if(*array_of_int_pointers[i] == number)
            return i;
    }
    return 0;
}
bool mod_array_of_pointers(int number, bool presence, int* array_of_int_pointers[], int index, bool checksum[])
{
    if(!presence)
    {
        array_of_int_pointers[index] = new int;
        *array_of_int_pointers[index] = number;
        checksum[index] = true;
        return true;
    }else{
        array_of_int_pointers[index] = array_of_int_pointers[find_index(number, array_of_int_pointers, index)];
        checksum[index] = false;
        return false;
    }
}

void deallocate(int* array_of_int_pointers[], bool checksum[], int index)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        if(checksum[i] == 1)
            delete array_of_int_pointers[i];
}
```

Comment: "new and delete in c++" - Generally, *avoid* those in modern C++.

Comment: you are right but I'm learning and its part of the thing i have to use for doing this exercise.

Comment: [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org/): `==14684== LEAK SUMMARY: ==14684==    definitely lost: 4 bytes in 1 blocks`.

Comment: So i'm leaking somewhere something or is just because i havent delete the dinamic pointers in the array of int pointers before return 0 ?

Comment: You leak memory. You do `new`, but you never do `delete`. I don't understand why you expect no memory leaks.

Comment: You need to use `delete`. Your teacher is right, if you dynamically allocate memory with `new`, you have to pair it with a `delete` later on. The thing is, you built your data structure in such a way that this is actually hard to accomplish. Normally you would go through all entries in `A` and call `delete` on them but since some entries hold the same pointer as other entries, you have to make sure to delete every pointer only once. Easy with smart pointers like [`shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr); hard to do manually

Comment: @Evg since program ends at return 0 and memory is released, I dont understand why should i do delete if I only make new for numbers that are not in the array... anyway i will try to make a function that somehow deletes just once the pointers in the array

Comment: Memory is released by the operating system. It's a bad practice to rely on that. Sometimes it's not just bad, it's disastrous. If _you_ do not release memory, it counts as a memory leak.

Comment: Delete has two purposes: 1. It releases the memory for reuse. You are right that this is unnecessary if the program is about to end anyway but I assume this exercise is supposed to simulate a smaller part of a larger program. 2. It calls the object's destructor. These can do other stuff like saving data to disk which may be necessary on program exit, too

Comment: It's not just about memory being released. Say the destructor also positions a robot arm in a safe position. N0ot deleting the object could result in the arm not being returned and carnage ensuing.

Comment: I've sorted it out using another array of bools which keeps trace of the new operator usage. So i can delete only once the values allocated on the heap.

Comment: _Just guessing:_ Your assignment is to input numbers in a loop. If a number is already in the array, do nothing (but continue looping). Otherwise, add the new number to the array at the lowest unused slot, and keep looping. (This is similar to the way `push_back` works on a vector.) If my guess is true, then it is a big mistake to increment `cursor` when `state` is false. You should only increment `cursor` at the same time as you increment `alloc_var`. If my guess is right, the deletion process is also super easy. Just delete the elements from `0` up to (but not including) `cursor`.

Comment: Your question is rather unlikely to help anyone in the future unless you distill the essence down to a [mre]. Drop everything except the memory management. And give some reason why you think your code does not leak memory. (Currently, your question explains why your code **does** leak memory.)

Comment: I've not needed to use `new` or `delete` in my C++ project for over 10 years.  As of C++11, they're not needed for most general C++ programming (except in cases such as making your own smart pointer, or other very advanced use cases).  Instead, there are general pointer `std::unique_ptr`, or containers `std::vector`, or specialized use-case objects like `std::string` — all of which are different kinds of smart pointers (the latter two are not usually thought of as "smart pointers", but under the covers they really are).

Answer (score 1):

##### Use a profiler

> I cant understand if I'm creating garbage with this program. The program works but I don't know how to check if I'm creating garbage somewhere.

The C++ language does not have any commands or functions to tell you if a program leaks memory. For that, you have to use tools like *Valgrind* to profile your memory usage.

Here is the way Wikipedia begins its [article about Valgrind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind):

> Valgrind is a programming tool for memory debugging, memory leak detection, and profiling.

You can read the rest, if you want to investigate further. Professional programmers use tools like Valgrind. Students, however, are not expected to master third-party tools at a time when they are still learning C++ itself.

##### Every `new` needs a corresponding `delete`

> In class the teacher said that every new has to have a delete somewhere.

Your teacher is right!

Best practice is to accomplish that by creating an [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) class to manage an object that uses dynamically allocated memory. The constructor calls operator `new` to allocate the object, and the destructor calls `delete` to deallocate it.

RAII is an acronym that stands for "resource aquisition is initialization," horrible name that was invented by no less than [Bjarne Stroustrup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bjarne_Stroustrup) himself. RAII focuses on the idea of *ownership*. The owner of an object is the one who is responsible for "cleaning up" when that object is deallocated. In the case of dynamically allocated memory, that means calling operator `delete`. For a class such as `std::fstream`, which is an RAII class, that means closing the file.

*Exception safety* is an overriding reason to use RAII classes. They are the only way to guarantee that an RAII object will be properly disposed of when an exception causes the unexpected termination of a program.

At this stage of your journey into C++, I will assume that you have not yet studied classes, so I will not give any source-code examples of an RAII class here.

The most natural solution to this problem would be to use an RAII class named `std::unique_ptr`. A `unique_ptr` is a *smart pointer* that behaves almost the same as regular pointer, except that it automatically calls operator `delete` on the object that it points to, when it is deleted itself.

Ownership is key. A `std::unique_ptr` owns the object it points to. So, when the destructor of a `std::unique_ptr` is invoked, because the pointer itself is being deallocated, it says, in effect, "If I'm getting deleted, I'm taking everything I own with me!"

Array `A`, in the program below, should be an array of `std::unique_ptr` objects. If it were, then the dynamically allocated array elements would automatically call delete on the integers they point to. Your program would not need to call operator `delete` at all. And if you also used a function called `std::make_unique`, which—trust me—you would, then your program would not need to call operator `new`, either.

##### With few exceptions, professionals do not use `using namespace std;`

There are drawbacks to `using namespace std;`. See [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). Your textbook probably should not be teaching you to use it.

Instead, pros just type `std::` every time they need to reference a name from the Standard Library. That is why I have used `std::cout`, `std::cin`, and so on, in this answer. (There are a few exceptions to this, mostly centered around something called *argument-dependent lookup*, but we won't go into them here.)

Unless your instructor gets mad, you should do the same thing. *And delete `using namespace std;` from your program!*

##### Defining the assignment

Although the OP does not explicity describe the assignment, from reading the code, I was able to determine that is was this:

> Write a program that inputs integers from the user, and adds them to an array that uses dynamically allocated elements. The values entered should be non-negative. When the user enters a negative value, that is the signal to quit.
>
> *No number should be stored more than once.* Each time the user enters a number, you should search the array to see if it is already stored there. If not, add it at the end of the allocated elements. Otherwise, do nothing. Either way, you should loop back, and ask the user to enter the next number.
>
> At the end of the program, display the number of elements that were allocated, followed by a list of them all.

Based on this, a good place to start is with a simple declaration of variables. There are no globals here. All the variables are defined at the beginning of function `main`.

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout <<
        "ARRAY INSERTER WITH DYNAMICALLY ALLOCATED ARRAY ELEMENTS"
        "\n"
        "\nEnter a negative number when you want to quit."
        "\n"
        "\nOtherwise, any non-negative number will be added to the array."
        "\nEach number is added only once. If you enter the same number "
        "\nmore than once, only the first entry is added to the array."
        "\n"
        "\nAt the end, we'll tell you how many allocations were "
        "\nmade to the array, and display them all."
        "\n\n";
    constexpr const std::size_t capacity{ 1000 };  // maximum size of array `A`
    std::size_t size{};  // allocated size of array `A`
    int* A[capacity]{};  // array `A`
    int n{};             // number to be entered by the user

    // ...

    return 0;
}
// end file: main.cpp
```

The only new thing here is the initialization of array `A`. The trailing braces cause each of its elements to be intialized to `nullptr`. The variables `size` and `n` are both initialized to `0`.

`std::size_t` is an alias for an unsigned integer type that is used by the compiler for array sizes and subscripts. It is also the type returned by operator `sizeof`. In general, you should prefer it over type `int`, when you use an array.

`std::size_t` is defined in the header `<cstddef>`, so that has been included here.

##### Function `get_int` – A safe way get input from the keyboard.

I like to call a function every time I ask the user for input. That way, I can validate the user's entries, and ask him to reenter them if they are invalid. You do not want to lock the user into a loop from which there is no exit, but you do want to keep looping until the user either gets it right, or else cancels the input.

That is what function `get_int` does below. The user can cancel by entering a negative number. Otherwise, garbage (i.e., non-numeric) entries will be rejected.

```cpp
int get_int()
{
    if (!std::cin.good())
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR: `get_int` called when "
            "`std::cin` was in a failed state.";
        return -1;  // This causes the caller to exit its loop.
    }
    int n;
    for (;;)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
        if (std::cin >> n)
            return n;
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        std::cout << "Invalid entry. Please reenter.\n\n";
    }
}
```

`for (;;)` is an infinite loop. Like I said, we're going to keep doing this, until the user get's it right. The only way to exit is by entering a valid integer for `n`, which then triggers the return statement.

It is important to test *every* input operation involving a user to see whether it succeeded or failed. That is what `if (std::cin >> n)` does. When a valid integer is entered, the expression `std::cin >> n` will be implicitly converted to a `bool`, with the value `true`. If input fails, then it will be converted to `false`, and the input stream will be placed into a "failed" state.

After a failed entry, it is important to call `std::cin.clear`, followed by `std::cin.ignore`. That is how you put `std::cin` back into a "good" state, and clear the garbage entry from the input stream. The call to function `ignore` discards all the keystrokes up to, and including, the newline character (i.e., "Enter key") at the end of the line.

I posted a fancier version of `get_int` in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77275060/22193627). It adds optional range checks for the entered values, and also optionally allows the user to cancel, by pressing Enter on a blank line. It is a little closer to what I use in my own work.

##### The main loop

One unexpected benefit of writing function `get_int` is the clean way in which the main loop of the program can now be written. There are two things it tests. First, it checks to see if there is any capacity left in array `A`, and, second, it checks to see if the user entered a non-negative number. When both answers are "yes," we keep looping.

```cpp
    while (size < capacity && (n = get_int()) >= 0)
    {
        // If the array does not contain `n`, add it at location 
        // `size`, and afterwards, increment `size`. Otherwise, 
        // if the array already contains `n`, do nothing.
    }
    std::cout.put('\n');

    // Print stats, and output array...

    // Run a loop to deallocate (i.e., `delete`) array elements...
```

The first check is just `size < capacity`. Keep looping so long as the allocated size is less than the overall capacity.

The second is a little trickier, and is worthy of explantion: `(n = get_int()) >= 0`.

On the left, we have `(n = get_int())`. This is an assignment. Variable `n` gets the value returned from `get_int`. What happens next, though, is that the assigned value is returned to the surrounding expression as the "answer" to the assignment. You end up with `(n) >= 0`. This is exactly the condition under which we want to keep looping. The user entered a non-negative number.

##### Delete array elements

The question in the OP has now become trivial. The allocated array elements have subscripts ranging from `0` up to (but not including) `size`. Run a simple loop that invokes operator `delete` on those elements.

I have omitted much of the detail. That is intentional. This should give you a good start, but I want to let you have some of the fun, too!