# What happens if I give a char input to an int datatype in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a program in C++ where I want to take an integer input from the user. I am using the cin function. In the terminal, I can still input characters without getting an error. What is the problem and how can I fix it?
Also when I input a character, what value is getting stored in the int variable?
P.S. Please ignore the poor code. I am just starting out. :)

```
int no;
cout << "Enter a no: "<<endl;
cin >> no;
int square = no*no;
cout << "The square of your no is: " << square << endl;
```

Comment: The stream will fail to parse the input, and set the `failbit` state, and `no` is set to `0` (assuming a recent compiler which defaults to the C++11 standard or later).

Comment: Surely you can add `cout << no << endl;` to see what you really got.  And, for what it's worth, `cin` is not a function.  It is a stream object.

Comment: `cin` doesn't report the errors by default, it'll just zero the number of an invalid input, or keep it unintialized. You either check for errors manually (`if (cin)` checks for success, `if (!cin)` checks for failure), or enable the automatic reporting via something like `std::cin.exceptions(~std::ios_base::goodbit);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problems with `std::cin` are experienced by all new C++ programmers.

The solution is to use a function that checks whether `std::cin` succeeded, and when it does not, asks the user to try again. Function `get_int`, below, is such a function.

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int get_int(std::string const& prompt)
{
    int n;
    for (;;)
    {
        std::cout << prompt;
        if (std::cin >> n)
            return n;
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        std::cout << "Invalid entry. Please reenter.\n\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    int x, y;
    x = get_int("Enter x: ");
    y = get_int("Enter y: ");
    std::cout << "x * y = " << x * y << '\n';
    return 0;
}
// end file: main.cpp
```

Output from a trial run:

```
Enter x: what?
Invalid entry. Please reenter.

Enter x: okay...
Invalid entry. Please reenter.

Enter x: 3
Enter y: 2
x * y = 6
```

`for (;;)` is an infinite loop. We're going to keep doing this, until the user get's it right. The only way to exit is by entering a valid integer for `n`, which then triggers the return statement.

It is important to test *every* input operation involving a user to see whether it succeeded or failed. That is what `if (std::cin >> n)` does. When a valid integer is entered, the expression `std::cin >> n` will be implicitly converted to a `bool`, with the value `true`. If input fails, then it will be converted to `false`, and the input stream will be placed into a "failed" state.

After a failed entry, it is important to call `std::cin.clear`, followed by `std::cin.ignore`. That is how you put `std::cin` back into a "good" state, and clear the garbage entry from the input stream. The call to function `ignore` discards all the keystrokes up to, and including, the newline character (i.e., "Enter key") at the end of the line.

I posted a fancier version of `get_int` in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77275060/22193627). It adds optional range checks for the entered values, and also optionally allows the user to cancel, by pressing Enter on a blank line. It is a little closer to what I use in my own work.