# Problem with output after incorrect input

Tags: c++, input, error-handling

I'm losing all hope, I can't seem to get this problem to disappear. I'm facing an error with my function that checks for input errors. I'm making a hotel reservation system for school. This is the current version of my function:

```
int inputError(const std::string& output, int min, int max, const std::string& errortext) {   
int number = 0;
bool error = false;
do {
    std::cout << output;
    std::string input;
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
    try {
        size_t pos;
        numero = std::stoi(input, &pos);
        if (pos != input.size()) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Incorrect input.");
        }
        if (number < min || number > max) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Out of range");
        }
    }
    catch (const std::invalid_argument& e) {
        error = true;
        std::cout << errortext << "\n";
    }
    catch (const std::out_of_range& e) {
        error = true;
        std::cout << errortext << "\n";
    }
} while (error);
return number;
}
```

Error I'm facing with this version:

When I input enter in the place of input, it reads it as an incorrect input, but after that it reads if the next input is correct or incorrect, but it doesn't move forward in the code. Here is an example with simplified texts so you get the point:

```
Welcome.
What would you like to do?
1: a
2: b
3: c
4: d
5: e

Input wasn't found in the menu.
Try again, please:
1: a
2: b
3: c
4: d
5: e
1
Input wasn't found in the menu.
Try again, please:
0
1: a
2: b
3: c
4: d
5: e
```

Older versions of the function:

```
int inputError(const std::string& output, int min, int max, const std::string& errorText) {   
int number = 0;
bool error;

do {
    error = false;
    std::cout << output;
    std::string input;
    std::cin >> input;

    std::istringstream iss(input);
    if (!(iss >> number) || number > max || number < min || iss.peek() != EOF) {    // 
        error = true;
        std::cout << errorText << "\n";   
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
} while (error);
return number;
}
```

Error I faced with this version:

if there is whitespace in the input, for example "1 5", it takes them, moves forward with the correct first number, and then marks the number 5 as incorrect input to the next place of input while nothing was inputted there.

```
int inputError(const std::string& output, int min, int max, const std::string& errorText) {   
int number = 0;
bool error;

do {
    error = false;
    std::cout << output;
    std::string input;
    std::getline(cin, input);

    std::istringstream iss(input);
    if (!(iss >> number) || number > max || number < min || iss.peek() != EOF) {    // 
        error = true;
        std::cout << errorText << "\n";   
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
} while (error);
return number;
}
```

Error I faced with this this version:

If there is an input such as this "1             1" it moves forward twice in the code, and I don't want that.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) Use the debugger to step through the code line by line, while monitoring variables and their values, to see what really happens.

Comment: This [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77275060/22193627) includes source code for function `get_int`, a robust function that inputs an integer from `std::cin`. `get_int` handles all the usual errors that can happen with `std::cin`, and loops until a valid integer is entered. It can also perform range checks on the numbers that are entered, rejecting any that are out of range. A detailed explanation describes every operation.

Comment: `iss.peek() != EOF` is not as clean as `!iss.eof()`. Before testing for errors, you can call the I/O manipulator [`std::ws`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ws) to discard unwanted whitespace following the entered number: `if (!iss.eof()) iss >> std::ws;` Skipping whitepace should take you to eof. If it does not, then you can declare an error, because you will have found extra characters after the entered number. So, follow up with a second test of `!iss.eof()`, which this time should trigger an error.

Comment: I found what was wrong with my code. I never reset the bool in the first code after an error is faced.

Answer (score 1):

You made several errors. The one which is probably the most confusing is the call to `cin.ignore`. It is unnecessary, because `std::cin` was not the stream that failed! The failure occurs on the stringstream `iss`. When you ignore characters on `std::cin`, you are ignoring future inputs, because the prior input did not fail, i.e., an entire line was successfully input as a string.

Another mistake was to declare an error when the stream `iss` was not at end-of-file. You should discard whitespace characters first, by calling the I/O manipulator [`std::cin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ws). After a number has been parsed, skipping whitespace should take you to the end of the line. That's the time to check, and require, that `iss.eof()` returns true. If not, you can declare an error, because you will have discovered extra characters, which follow the number that was entered.

Finally, you should check the call to `getline`, just to be sure that `std::cin` was not already in a failed state when your function was entered.

Here is one way to correct those errors.

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int inputError(
    const std::string& output,
    int min, 
    int max, 
    const std::string& errorText)
{
    int number = 0;
    bool error;
    do {
        error = false;
        std::cout << output;
        std::string input;

        // Check this I/O operation!
        if (!std::getline(std::cin, input))
        {
            std::cout << "`getline` failed unexpectedly. Returning `0`...\n\n";
            return 0;
        }

        std::istringstream iss(input);

        // Input number AND discard any trailing whitespace.
        // This should force `iss` to end-of-file, because only 
        // whitespace characters should follow the number.
        if ((iss >> number) && !iss.eof())
                iss >> std::ws;

        // Now you can test for other errors, including `!iss.eof()`.
        if (iss.fail() || !iss.eof() || number > max || number < min) {
            error = true;
            std::cout << errorText << "\n\n";

            // These lines are not needed, because the failure was with
            // the stream `iss`, not the stream `std::cin`.
            // 
            // std::cin.clear();
            // std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
    } while (error);
    return number;
}

int main()
{
    int x = inputError("Enter x between 1 and 10: ", 1, 10, 
        "Invalid entry. Please reenter.");
    std::cout << "\nYou entered " << x << "\n\n";
    return 0;
}
// end file: main.cpp
```

Here is the output from a trial run.

```
Enter x between 1 and 10: 1 1
Invalid entry. Please reenter.

Enter x between 1 and 10: 1 5
Invalid entry. Please reenter.

Enter x between 1 and 10: 1

You entered 1
```