# Need this C++ code to delete only the line that I find in a TXT file after confirming yes

Tags: c++

I tried combining a my search function with a line delete function. Each on their own work perfectly. But after many attempts I cant seem to get them to work together. Right now this code will delete the line I want to delete and every line above it. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. I've only been coding for less than a week and this is for an important school project. Please help!

Info inside the text file:

1. Barry Bonds 326598
2. Michael Jordan 784512
3. Lebron James 545689
4. Steph Curry 878512
5. Joe Montana 656231
6. Deebo Samuel 783265
7. Leonardo Dicaprio 123645

Example: If I type James, the code currently shows me the Lebron James record. When I confirm, it deletes the Lebron James record and all the records above it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <cassert>
 
using namespace std;
 
void search()
{
    struct employee 
    {
        string firstname;
        string lastname;
        string user_id;  
    };
 
    ifstream Myfile;
    Myfile.open("employeerecords.txt");
    ofstream temp;
    temp.open("temp.txt");
 
    vector<employee> employees;
 
    string deleteline;
    string line;
    string search;
    string confirm;
    int offset;
 
    cout << "\nType 'cancel' to return to menu\n\n";
    cout << "Enter Employee Name or ID: ";
    cin >> search;
 
    if (search == "cancel")
    {
        /*void hrmenu();
        hrmenu();*/
    } 
    else if (Myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (!Myfile.eof())
        {
            while(getline(Myfile, line))
            {
                if ((offset = line.find(search, 0)) != string::npos)
                {
                    istringstream ss(line);
                    istream_iterator<string> begin(ss), end;
                    vector<string> words(begin, end); 
 
                    assert(words.size() >= 3); 
 
                    int n = words.size() - 1;
                    employee e { words[0], words[n-1], words[n] };
                    for (int i = 1 ; i < n - 3 ; i++) e.firstname += " " + words[i];
 
                    employees.push_back(e);
 
                    for(auto && e : employees)
                        cout << "Employee Name: "<<e.firstname<< " "<<e.lastname << '\n'
                             << "User ID: "<<e.user_id << '\n'
                             << "-------------------" << '\n';
 
                    cout << "Is this the record you want to delete? (Y/N): ";
                    cin >> confirm;
 
                    if (confirm == "Y")
                    {
                        while(getline(Myfile, line))
                        {
                            if (line != search)
                            {
                                temp << line << endl;
                            }
                        }
                    }
            
                    temp.close();
                    Myfile.close();
                    remove("employeerecord.txt");
                    rename("temp.txt","employeerecords.txt"); 
                }
            }
        }
        Myfile.close();
    }
    else
        cout << "File opening error" << endl;
    return;
}
 
int main()
{
    void search();
    search();
}
```

Comment: Don't use `endl`, you slow down the output dramatically.

Comment: *it doesn't work as expected.* And what is expected, what is the actual result?

Comment: Read the whole file into a vector, one element per line. Remove the line you want to remove from the vector. Recreate the file, and write out all remaining elements of the vector.

Comment: "it doesn't work as expected. And what is expected, what is the actual result?"

did you read the first statement? I said the exact problem and what I was trying to achieve. The small piece of code below deletes one line from a TXT file that matches input from the user. But inside my code it deletes that line and every line above it.

Comment: did not cross your mind to post the first 2 or 4 lines of such `"employeerecords.txt"` file you used while getting this unexpected result? The program seems a bit over-complicated.

Comment: Side note: The line `void search();` (function declaration for a function that is already defined) in `main()`  is completely redundant.

Comment: @arfneto I didn't think it was necessary. And like I said, I just started coding last week. This is for school and tbh i'm STRUGGLING....

I will edit and add for more incite.

Comment: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: @JesperJuhl this is for a larger project. This is just a piece of the puzzle. I could have wrote it in main, but im doing more things with it. That's just to get the code to run inside the compiler. Even that may be wrong IDK. Im new to this....

Comment: @JesperJuhl thats news to me.

Comment: You'll be glad to hear that you don't need anyone's help to figure this out, just a tool you already have: your debugger! This is exactly what a debugger is for: it runs your program, one line at a time, and [shows you what's happening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/)!! This is something that's every C++ developer must know how to do. With your debugger's help you'll able to quickly find all problems in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help. Have you tried using your debugger, already? If not, why not? What did your debugger show you?

Comment: Well, I can tell you that you have an input text file for your code and you are asking about this code in a public site. If I think I can help you  I will need to type in a new test file. And I will never know about your original one. It is simpler for you and for the ones that eventually want to help YOU that you type in also at least the first few lines of one test file you are using.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik no errors. The code executes. But the results are wrong. I need it to delete the line I search for. It's deleting that line and every one above it.

Comment: @arfneto Gotcha. I added it to the original post.

Comment: What did your debugger show you as the reason why "results are wrong"? Which line on the shown code was the last one while the results were right, until that ppint, and where exactly and at which point did the program's behavior diverge and why, specifically? Did you understand what your debugger was telling you was happening?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Im realizing I don't even know how to the use the debugger properly at this point. I just figured out to set break points as we have been talking. And honestly im not even so sure I understand how to do that properly. So no, I dont understand :(

Comment: Well, then, sounds like that's your next step: learn "how to use the debugger properly". Specifically, not just setitng breakpoints, but also stepping through the code, one line at a time, inspecting the values of all variables, setting watches on variables so that the program's execution stops as soon as the variable's value changes, and many other debugging and analytical tools. Learning how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. Everyone who works with C++ must learn how to use a debugger, Stackoverflow is not meant to be a replacement for a debugger.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik i hear you and you are not wrong, but right now im just trying to pass a class. My goal is not to be a c++ coder....

Comment: Given the number of textbooks that use it, you may be surprised to learn that professional programmers do not use `using namespace std;` in production code. Neither should you. Instead, professionals just type `std::` every time they need to reference a name from the Standard Library. There are a few exceptions to this, mostly centered around something called _argument-dependent lookup_, but there is not enough space to go into them here. (_Hint:_ overloads for `std::swap`  frequently use ADL.)

Comment: @tbxfreeware can someone actually help me fix this code to work properly though? please!

Comment: Restructure your function to FIRST read the entire file into `employees`, THEN ask for a name to search, then use `employees.erase` to remove the offending line, finally rewrite the file. That will fix your problem because you currently read *and throw away* all lines before the matching line.

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious why your program deletes all the employees before the one to be deleted.

You are doing while(getline(Myfile, line)) for searching which is fine. But you are using the same while(getline(Myfile, line)) after confirming to delete an employee, which means that you are proceeding within the same file.
In fact, you are not deleting employees in the old file but copying all employees after the one to be deleted.
The issue is that you are not copying any employee until you confirm to delete the searched employee and only start copying employees beneath the deleted employee.
You can easily fix that by adding the following else clause for that searching if clause

```
if ((offset = line.find(search, 0)) != string::npos)
{
   ...
   // your codes
   ...
}
else
{
   temp << line << endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution suggested by @Botje.

> Restructure your function to FIRST read the entire file into employees, THEN ask for a name to search, then use employees.erase to remove the offending line, finally rewrite the file. That will fix your problem because you currently read and throw away all lines before the matching line.

When faced with an assignment to read records from a file, such as this one, *most students do not think big enough*. They usually stop at the struct that holds a single record. In this case, that is struct `employee`.

It is often better to go two steps further.

The key is to imagine reading the entire file into a vector. With the records in a vector, you can close the file, and forget about it, until it comes time rewrite it. So, the second struct is struct `employee_vector`, which encapsulates a vector of `employee` objects, and provides functions to manage it. Many of those functions are simple *wrappers*, which expose the member functions of the vector.

Both structs, `employee` and `employee_vector`, can have stream operator functions (`operator<<` and `operator>>`) to read and write records from a stream. Struct `employee` does the heavy lifting. It has to have a tough-as-nails stream extraction operator that detects any sort of error that might happen. Struct `employee_vector` has it easy. All it does is run a loop, reading one record at a time, by calling the operator from struct `employee`.

Neither one of these structs cares about the file. They do not know about it, and they do not reference it. Their stream operators are written in terms of `std::istream` and `std::ostream`, rather than `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream`. Removing any knowledge about the file creates a nice division of labor.

By now, of course, you will have realized that struct `employee_file` is the third member of our trio. It handles the `file_name`, and has member functions `read` and `write` that handle the I/O. Those two functions are almost trivial, because *they call the stream operators in `employee_vector` to do the actual work!* The only real job they have is opening files, and reporting file-open failures.

##### Struct `employee`

In an informal design, `employee`, `employee_vector`, and `employee_file` can all be structs. The data members in struct `employee`, for example, do not need to have *setter* and *getter* functions. Clients can just access its members directly.

Here is a look at struct `employee`.

```cpp
struct employee
{
    // The `lastname` field is placed first in the struct. This allows 
    // `std::sort` to use the comparison functions generated by the 
    // defaulted spaceship operator below, when it compares two employee
    // records.

    std::string lastname;
    std::string firstname;
    std::string user_id;

    auto operator<=> (employee const&) const
        = default;

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& ost, employee const& e)
    {
        ost << e.firstname
            << ' ' << e.lastname
            << ' ' << e.user_id
            << '\n';
        return ost;
    }

    friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& ist, employee& e)
    {
        std::string s;
        if (!std::getline(ist, s))
        {
            // It is okay for `std::getline` to fail, but only if 
            // we are at end-of-file. Otherwise, throw an exception.
            if (!ist.eof())
                throw std::runtime_error(
                    "Input stream failed while reading `employee`."
                    "\nCall to `std::getline` failed unexpectedly.");
            return ist;
        }

        // After reading all three fields from a stringstream, a check 
        // is made that nothing more remains in the stringstream. We 
        // want the stream to hit end-of-file.

        std::stringstream sst{ s };
        sst >> e.firstname >> e.lastname >> e.user_id;
        if (!sst.fail() && !sst.eof())
            sst >> std::ws;
        if (sst.fail() || !sst.eof())
        {
            // Place the stream into a failed state.
            ist.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
            throw std::runtime_error(
                "Input stream failed while reading `employee` record. "
                "\nInvalid `employee` record: \"" + s + '"');
        }
        return ist;
    }
};
```

##### Struct `employee_vector`

In addition to the `std::vector` it manages, struct `employee_vector` also has a `std::map`. It uses the map to index the field `user_id`, and thereby enforce its uniqueness. No two employees can have the same `user_id`. Pay close attention to `operator>>`, to see how this is implemented.

There are also subscripting operators, and a host of other functions, that wrap the corresponding functions of the vector.

A trio of functions, `display`, `find_matches`, and `erase`, can be used by the `employee_app`, to assist in the work of deleting employees.

```cpp
struct employee_vector
{
    using map_type = std::map<std::string, std::size_t>;
    using vector_type = std::vector<employee>;

    map_type lookup_user_id;
    vector_type employees;

    void clear() {
        lookup_user_id.clear();
        employees.clear();
    }
    void display() {
        for (std::size_t i{}; i < employees.size(); ++i)
            std::cout << "  " << i + 1 << ". " << employees[i];
        std::cout.put('\n');
    }
    void erase(std::size_t const i) {
        if (i >= employees.size())
            throw std::runtime_error("`employee_vector` subscript "
                "out of range in member function `erase`");
        lookup_user_id.erase(employees[i].user_id);
        employees.erase(employees.begin() + i);
    }
    std::vector<std::size_t> find_matches(std::string const& search_str)
    {
        // Return a vector of subscripts of all the records that 
        // match parameter `search_str`.
        auto const s{ tbx::to_lower(search_str) };
        std::vector<std::size_t> matches;
        for (std::size_t i{}; i < employees.size(); ++i)
        {
            auto e{ employees[i] };
            tbx::to_lower_in_place(e.lastname);
            tbx::to_lower_in_place(e.firstname);
            tbx::to_lower_in_place(e.user_id);
            if (e.lastname.contains(s) ||
                e.firstname.contains(s) ||
                e.user_id.contains(s)
                )
                matches.push_back(i);
        }
        return matches;
    }
    void emplace_back(employee const& e) {
        employees.emplace_back(e);
    }
    void emplace_back(employee&& e) {
        employees.emplace_back(std::move(e));
    }
    std::size_t size() const {
        return employees.size();
    }
    void sort() {
        std::sort(employees.begin(), employees.end());
    }
    vector_type& operator()() {
        return employees;
    }
    vector_type const& operator()() const {
        return employees;
    }
    employee& operator[](std::size_t const i) {
        return employees[i];
    }
    employee const& operator[](std::size_t const i) const {
        return employees[i];
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& ost, employee_vector const& employees)
    {
        for (auto const& employee : employees())
            ost << employee;
        return ost;
    }
    friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& ist, employee_vector& employees)
    {
        employees.clear();
        employee e;
        while (ist >> e)
        {
            if (employees.lookup_user_id.contains(e.user_id))
            {
                auto const i{ employees.lookup_user_id[e.user_id] };
                auto const e2{ employees[i] };
                std::stringstream sst;
                sst << "Error reading employees: Duplicate `user_id`."
                    << "\nTwo records have the same user id."
                    << "\n 1. " << e2
                    << "\n 2. " << e
                    << "\n";
                throw std::runtime_error(sst.str());
            }
            employees.lookup_user_id[e.user_id] = employees.size();
            employees.emplace_back(e);
        }
        return ist;
    }
};
```

##### Struct `employee_file`

Given the power of the two structs above, is it not surprising that struct `employee_file` is so simple. Member functions `read` and `write` both take a reference to an `employee_vector`, and then call that vector's stream operators to do the work of insertion and extraction.

Note that the file is not opened in the constructor. That is delayed until either `read` or `write` is invoked. Note, as well, that the file is not left hanging open. It is closed, as soon as it is not needed.

```cpp
struct employee_file
{
    std::string file_name;

    explicit employee_file(std::string const& file_name)
        : file_name{ file_name }
    {}

    bool read(employee_vector& employees)
    {
        std::ifstream ist{ file_name };
        if (!ist.is_open())
            return false;

        try { 
            ist >> employees; 
            ist.close();
        }
        catch (std::exception const& e) { 
            ist.close();
            std::cout << e.what() << "\n\n";
            throw;
        }

        // Any read error will throw an exception.
        // If we make it to this point, no exceptions 
        // were thrown. Return `true` to indicate 
        // that the file was read successfully.

        return true;
    }

    bool write(employee_vector const& employees)
    {
        std::ofstream ost{ file_name };
        if (!ost.is_open())
            return false;
        ost << employees;
        ost.close();
        return true;
    }
};
```

##### Struct `employee_app`

I used one other major struct for this program: `employee_app`.
It handles menu functions, and is the driver for the whole
project.

But I am going to leave that one to you. Most of the pieces are given above. Now you get to exercise your ingenuity to engineer a solution of your own.

Here is sample output from the one I created.

```
EMPLOYEE DELETER

MAIN MENU

 1. Display employees
 2. Delete employee
 3. Quit

Choice: 1


  1. Barry Bonds 326598
  2. Michael Jordan 784512
  3. Lebron James 545689
  4. Steph Curry 878512
  5. Joe Montana 656231
  6. Deebo Samuel 783265
  7. Leonardo Dicaprio 123645


MAIN MENU

 1. Display employees
 2. Delete employee
 3. Quit

Choice: 2


ENTER SEARCH STRING

 - Enter some text to search for.
 - All fields will be searched.
 - Partial entries are okay, even a single letter or digit.
 - Press Enter to cancel.

Search for: 12


CONFIRM DELETION

  1. Michael Jordan 784512
  2. Steph Curry 878512
  3. Leonardo Dicaprio 123645

Enter the number of the record you want to delete.
Press Enter to cancel.

Choice:
Canceled...


MAIN MENU

 1. Display employees
 2. Delete employee
 3. Quit

Choice: 2


ENTER SEARCH STRING

 - Enter some text to search for.
 - All fields will be searched.
 - Partial entries are okay, even a single letter or digit.
 - Press Enter to cancel.

Search for: L


CONFIRM DELETION

  1. Michael Jordan 784512
  2. Lebron James 545689
  3. Deebo Samuel 783265
  4. Leonardo Dicaprio 123645

Enter the number of the record you want to delete.
Press Enter to cancel.

Choice: 4

Record deleted.


MAIN MENU

 1. Display employees
 2. Delete employee
 3. Quit

Choice: 1


  1. Barry Bonds 326598
  2. Michael Jordan 784512
  3. Lebron James 545689
  4. Steph Curry 878512
  5. Joe Montana 656231
  6. Deebo Samuel 783265


MAIN MENU

 1. Display employees
 2. Delete employee
 3. Quit

Choice: 3


Exiting...
```

##### Toolbox functions

I used a few functions from my toolox in the code above. The most useful was function `get_int`, which handles keyboard input. It prompts the user to enter an integer within a certain range, and loops until the user either gets it right, or cancels. The details of its operation can be found in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77275060/22193627).

```cpp
#pragma once
// tbx.utility.h
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <string>

namespace tbx
{
    bool get_double(
        std::string const& prompt,
        double& value,
        double const lowest = std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest(),
        double const max = std::numeric_limits<double>::max(),
        bool const cancel_is_allowed = true,
        std::istream& ist = std::cin,
        std::ostream& ost = std::cout);

    bool get_int(
        std::string const& prompt,
        int& value,
        int const min = std::numeric_limits<int>::min(),
        int const max = std::numeric_limits<int>::max(),
        bool const cancel_is_allowed = true,
        std::istream& ist = std::cin,
        std::ostream& ost = std::cout);

    void press_enter_to_continue(
        std::istream& ist = std::cin,
        std::ostream& ost = std::cout);

    std::string to_lower(std::string s) noexcept;
    void to_lower_in_place(std::string& s) noexcept;
    std::string to_upper(std::string s) noexcept;
    void to_upper_in_place(std::string& s) noexcept;
    std::string trim_whitespace(std::string const& s);

}
// end file: tbx.utility.h
```

```cpp
// tbx.utility.cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

#include "tbx.utility.h"

namespace tbx
{
    //==================================================================
    // get_double
    //==================================================================
    bool get_double(
        std::string const& prompt,
        double& value,
        double const lowest,
        double const max,
        bool const cancel_is_allowed,
        std::istream& ist,
        std::ostream& ost)
    {
        std::string s;
        for (;;)
        {
            value = 0;
            if (!prompt.empty())
                ost << prompt;
            else if (cancel_is_allowed)
                ost << "Enter a floating point value (press Enter to cancel): ";
            else
                ost << "Enter a floating point value: ";
            if (!std::getline(ist, s))
            {
                ost << "\nERROR: `std::getline` failed unexpectedly.\n\n";
                return false;
            }
            s = tbx::trim_whitespace(s);
            if (s.empty())
            {
                if (cancel_is_allowed)
                {
                    ost << "Canceled...\n\n";
                    return false;
                }
                ost << "Blank lines are not allowed. Please reenter.\n\n";
                continue;
            }
            std::stringstream sst(s);
            sst >> value;
            bool parses{ sst.eof() && !sst.fail() };
            bool is_in_range{ parses && lowest <= value && value <= max };
            if (is_in_range)
                return true;
            if (!parses)
                ost << "Entries must be floating point values. Please reenter.\n\n";
            else if (lowest != std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest()
                && max != std::numeric_limits<double>::max())
                ost << value << " is out of range. Please reenter.\n"
                << "Entries must be floating point values between " << lowest << " and " << max << ".\n\n";
            else if (lowest != std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest())
                ost << value << " is out of range. Please reenter.\n"
                << "Entries must be floating point values greater than or equal to " << lowest << ".\n\n";
            else
                ost << value << " is out of range. Please reenter.\n"
                << "Entries must be floating point values less than or equal to " << max << ".\n\n";
        }
    }
    //==================================================================
    // get_int
    //==================================================================
    bool get_int(
        std::string const& prompt,
        int& value,
        int const min,
        int const max,
        bool const cancel_is_allowed,
        std::istream& ist,
        std::ostream& ost)
    {
        std::string s;
        for (;;)
        {
            value = 0;
            if (!prompt.empty())
                ost << prompt;
            else if (cancel_is_allowed)
                ost << "Enter an integer (press Enter to cancel): ";
            else
                ost << "Enter an integer: ";
            if (!std::getline(ist, s))
            {
                ost << "\nERROR: `std::getline` failed unexpectedly.\n\n";
                return false;
            }
            s = tbx::trim_whitespace(s);
            if (s.empty())
            {
                if (cancel_is_allowed)
                {
                    ost << "Canceled...\n\n";
                    return false;
                }
                ost << "Blank lines are not allowed. Please reenter.\n\n";
                continue;
            }
            std::stringstream sst(s);
            sst >> value;
            bool parses{ sst.eof() && !sst.fail() };
            bool is_in_range{ parses && min <= value && value <= max };
            if (is_in_range)
                return true;
            if (!parses)
                ost << "Entries must be integers. Please reenter.\n\n";
            else if (min != std::numeric_limits<int>::min()
                && max != std::numeric_limits<int>::max())
                ost << value << " is out of range. Please reenter.\n"
                << "Entries must be integers between " << min << " and " << max << ".\n\n";
            else if (min != std::numeric_limits<int>::min())
                ost << value << " is out of range. Please reenter.\n"
                << "Entries must be integers greater than or equal to " << min << ".\n\n";
            else
                ost << value << " is out of range. Please reenter.\n"
                << "Entries must be integers less than or equal to " << max << ".\n\n";
        }
    }
    //==================================================================
    // press_enter_to_continue
    //==================================================================
    void press_enter_to_continue(std::istream& ist, std::ostream& ost)
    {
        std::string s;
        for (;;) {
            ost << "Press Enter to continue...";
            if (!std::getline(ist, s)) {
                ost << "\nERROR: `std::getline` failed unexpectedly.\n\n";
                return;
            }
            if (tbx::trim_whitespace(s).empty()) {
                ost.put('\n');
                return;
            }
            ost << "Invalid entry. Please reenter.\n";
        }
    }
    //==================================================================
    // to_lower
    //==================================================================
    std::string to_lower(std::string s) noexcept
    {
        tbx::to_lower_in_place(s);
        return s;
    }
    //==================================================================
    // to_lower_in_place
    //==================================================================
    void to_lower_in_place(std::string& s) noexcept
    {
        std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(),
            [](unsigned char c) {
                return static_cast<char>(std::tolower(c));
            }
        );
    }
    //==================================================================
    // to_upper
    //==================================================================
    std::string to_upper(std::string s) noexcept
    {
        tbx::to_upper_in_place(s);
        return s;
    }
    //==================================================================
    // to_upper_in_place
    //==================================================================
    void to_upper_in_place(std::string& s) noexcept
    {
        std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(),
            [](unsigned char c) {
                return static_cast<char>(std::toupper(c));
            }
        );
    }
    //==================================================================
    // trim_whitespace
    //==================================================================
    auto trim_whitespace(std::string const& s) -> std::string
    {
        // Trim leading and trailing whitespace from string `s`.
        auto const first{ s.find_first_not_of(" \f\n\r\t\v") };
        if (first == std::string::npos)
            return {};
        auto const last{ s.find_last_not_of(" \f\n\r\t\v") };
        enum : std::string::size_type { one = 1u };
        return s.substr(first, (last - first + one));
    }
}
// end file: tbx.utility.cpp
```